# Change and restore pastetoggle

Tags: vim, paste

Suppose that my `pastetoggle` is set to `<F10>`, if I run `echo &pastetoggle` it prints out `<80>k;` (Question number 1) how can I reach its value as string `"<F10>"` instead of this `<80>k;` code. I mean is it possible to set a variable to `"<F10>"` based on the value of `pastetoggle`?

Now if I run `let @a=&pastetoggle` and then run `echo @a` it prints out the same `<80>k;` string, but if I run `let &pastetoggle=@a` afterwards and run `echo &pastetogggle` it prints out `<80><fe>Xk;` (Question number 2) why? (Question number 3) how can I set `pastetoggle` based on value in `@a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<80>k;` is the internal keycode representation of `<F10>`; unfortunately, as you've found out, it cannot be saved and then reassigned to `&pastetoggle`.

You can get the "actual" value via

```
:set pastetoggle?
```

To capture that, you'd have to use `:redir` and string extraction:

```
redir => setOutput
    silent! set pastetoggle?
redir END
let pasteToggleKey = matchstr(setOutput, 'pastetoggle=\zs.*')
echo pasteToggleKey
```

Comment: Thanks, it completely satisfies my need, so I upvoted your answer. But it's a bit complicated solution, so I wait few days to see if someone has a simpler solution.